# How to run artisan outside of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

Is it possible to run Artisan commands from a script that is not part of Laravel?

How can I import artisan into my script?

```
<?php

 Artisan::call('some:command');
```

This script will is not part of Laravel and just a regular old php file. My question is, how can I import `Artisan` into my script?

My final goal, is to automate the installation of my app, I need to run a migrations, seeds and a couple other things.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a bash script. The set up for that to work will probably be larger than setting up the Laravel project

Comment: You can always just create an instance of the command and call the `handle` method yourself, so long as the necessary dependencies are installed. Including an `autoload.php` file in the command would probably get you close though.

Comment: @devk, how can we write php artisan down command in bash script which is not part of laravel command?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, you cannot use artisan without Laravel as it is not a stand-alone package and requires the full Laravel framework.

However, Artisan is based on the Symfony Console package which can be added to your script as a stand-alone package, which is the closest you will get to Artisan without writing a custom bash script.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html